# Do we have a canonical answer to why the Page Object pattern is important?

Tags: discussion

The nearest I could find was [What is page object modelling? and Why is it so important?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5059/what-is-page-object-modelling-and-why-is-it-so-important) ... which is over 6 years old and has less than 500 views.

Is there a better one to refer to, or could some folks with more experience using POM provide some more canonical answers there? I considered putting a bounty on that question to solicit canonical answers but wanted to make sure there wasn't already a better question around.

Part of why I'm asking is I've been playing around with Cypress.io, and their dev team seems to not quite grasp the actual benefits of the pattern (and therefore doesn't appear to put much effort or interest into supporting it). E.g. [this seed question by one of their devs on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50685302/page-object-pattern-in-cypress) and [this answer in their FAQ](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html#Can-I-use-the-Page-Object-pattern).

I've seen plenty of experts here talk about the importance of POM for writing maintainable UI tests, but those responses are scattered throughout the site. It would be nice to have a canonical link to point at when advocating for supporting this pattern as a first-class citizen, and I imagine it would be useful in many other scenarios as well.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is an excellent idea.

You're more than welcome to create a canonical question with references to some of the answers scattered through the site and pull in your own answer, if nobody else does it before you (particularly since you've obviously searched for a canonical answer).

Comment: Sounds good. Created: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/37125/how-would-you-convince-someone-that-the-page-object-model-is-important

Answer (score 2):

Page Objects make specifications readable and maintainable.

Good code is easily to read and change.  Page objects help that happen.

Comment: And the tooth fairy leaves me a dollar every time I put a tooth under the pillow.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here.  I've used Page Objects for all object identifiers in 4 jobs in a row and it has helped make specs easy to maintain.  Are you saying you think that is just a dream?